# CodeIgniter Adding File Upload to Existing Edit Function

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm new at CodeIgniter and just ran through a NetTuts intro lesson. 
I'm now trying to build on what I've learned.

How would I be able to add a file upload field to an existing page type? Below is my Edit function from the Page Controller. It's a basic page with Title, Slug, Body, Template, Parent_ID. How would I add the File upload data to it?

I want to upload the document to an 'Uploads' directory, and save its File Path into the existing Page table. I've already added a '**file**' column to the Page table.

```
    public function edit ($id = NULL)
{
    // Fetch a page or set a new one
    if ($id) {
        $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get($id);
        count($this->data['page']) || $this->data['errors'][] = 'page could not be found';
    }
    else {
        $this->data['page'] = $this->page_m->get_new();
    }

    // Pages for dropdown
    $this->data['pages_no_parents'] = $this->page_m->get_no_parents();

    // Set up the form
    $rules = $this->page_m->rules;
    $this->form_validation->set_rules($rules);

    // Process the form
    if ($this->form_validation->run() == TRUE) {
        $data = $this->page_m->array_from_post(array(
            'title', 
            'slug', 
            'body', 
            'template', 
            'parent_id'
        ));
        $this->page_m->save($data, $id);
        redirect('admin/page');
    }

    // Load the view
    $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/page/edit';
    $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main', $this->data);
}
```

I've looked at the File Upload Class by CodeIgniter. These are the configurations I'd like to use, but I don't know how to integrate this to work with my Page type.

```
        $config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
        $config['max_size'] = '1000000';
        $this->load->library('upload', $config);
```

If I can get pointed in the right direction on how to get the data into my DB and the file into my directory, I believe I can figure out how to display it all in my View.

Thank you!

** EDIT (now with form output) **

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
<table class="table">
    <tr>
        <td>Parent</td>
        <td><?php echo form_dropdown('parent_id', $pages_no_parents, $this->input->post('parent_id') ? $this->input->post('parent_id') : $page->parent_id); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Template</td>
        <td><?php echo form_dropdown('template', array('page' => 'Page', 'news_archive' => 'News Archive', 'homepage' => 'Homepage'), $this->input->post('template') ? $this->input->post('template') : $page->template); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Title</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('title', set_value('title', $page->title)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Slug</td>
        <td><?php echo form_input('slug', set_value('slug', $page->slug)); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Body</td>
        <td><?php echo form_textarea('body', set_value('body', $page->body), 'class="tinymce"'); ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>File Upload</td>
        <td><?php echo form_upload('userfile', set_value('userfile', $page->userfile)) ?></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td><?php echo form_submit('submit', 'Save', 'class="btn btn-primary"'); ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php echo form_close();?>
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to upload, im confused. Can you clear that up? Are you submitting a form? if so, does the form have an input with type `file`? Can you provide HTML?

Comment: I want to add a file upload field to upload and display a link to a PDF file on the page.

Comment: ok, so far I see that you are saving the form's post values. Do you want to upload the PDF after or before the save method? Also, can you provide the HTML? This will show us if you are setting up your form the right way in order to grab the file you want to upload

Comment: Ok, I edited the original question. You should see the form output info.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure but added this code before save the record.

```
$this->load->library('upload', $config);
$this->upload->initialize($config);                             
if(!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile'))                       
{
  $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());   
  $this->load->view('upload_form', $error);                     
}
else
{
  $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());        
  //do stuff
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML, make sure you change this:

```
<?php echo form_open(); ?>
```

to this:

```
<?php echo form_open_multipart();?>
```

In order for PHP to read the `$_FILES` you submit. Once you do that, process the upload like this:

```
$this->load->library('upload');
$config['upload_path'] = './uploads';
$config['allowed_types'] = 'pdf';
$config['max_size'] = '1000000';
$this->upload->initialize($config);
if ($this->upload->do_upload("userfile")) {
   //your success code
   $upload_data = $this->upload->data();
   $data_to_save['file_name'] = $upload_data['file_name'];
} else {
   //your failure code
   var_dump($this->upload->display_errors());
}
```